# Uploading files into Google Persistent Disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Google Container Engine to run docker containers that use persistent disks for data storing, the disks are mounted as volumes.

It's all well, except I was wondering if there is a standard way to directly access and upload/download files to/from persistent disks used this way (that is, not attached to a particular VM) or should I run a separate container with FTP or some such using the same volumes in order to do that? The later seems a bit of an overkill for such a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using persistent disks, you could use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/). It has a pretty simple CLI and API for both uploading your files and pulling them into the containers that need them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not really applicable in our case. The latency and speed is unacceptable for our current architecture, though perhaps we might redesign one day and unload non-critical parts into the cloud storage.